# Connection Pool returning an instance of Redis and not ConnectionPool

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis

I am trying to make my Rails app use `Resque` for managing workers.  But, I would like to continue using the ConnectionPool gem.

I have this in an initializer:

```
puts ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]

uri = (not ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"].nil?) ? URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]) : nil

# at this point, debugger confirms $redis is nil
$redis = ConnectionPool::Wrapper.new(:size => 5, :timeout => 3) { 
  if uri.nil?
    Redis.connect
  else
    Redis.connect(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password) 
  end
}

$redis # just put this in here for the debugger
       # At this point, $redis is #<Redis:0x007fb1b0036bf0>
       # when it should be an instance of ConnectionPool::Wrapper
```

Does anyone have an idea why `$redis` would not be returned as an instance `ConnectionPool::Wrapper`?

I've searched in all the gems source code, nowhere does it set the value of `$redis`.  In ConnectionPool's source code, I did not find anything where it would return an instance of `Redis` instead of itself.

This only happens when I switched from DelayedJob to Resque.  So, it would seem that is the problem.  However, I'm at a loss.

I am using Unicorn.  Here's that file in `config`.

```
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # Replace with MongoDB or whatever
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from ActiveRecord')
  end

  # If you are using Redis but not Resque, change this
  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis.quit
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from Redis')
  end

  sleep 1
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # Replace with MongoDB or whatever
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to ActiveRecord')
  end

  # If you are using Redis but not Resque, change this
  if defined?(Resque)
    # Yes, commented the Resque out for debugging, still get the same problem.
    #Resque.redis = ENV['REDISTOGO_URL']
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
  end
end
```

And finally, the Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: env TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
```

I'm using `foreman` in my develop environment.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> You can use ConnectionPool::Wrapper to wrap a single global connection.

I looks like the `ConnectionPool::Wrapper` is meant to wrap a single connection to Redis as a convenience for migrating large applications from using Redis directly to using `ConnectionPool`s

If you call `$redis.with`, you get the `#with` defined by `ConnectionPool`

To get an actual connection pool, just change your

```
ConnectionPool::Wrapper.new(:size => 5, :timeout => 3) { #redis logic }
```

to

```
ConnectionPool.new(:size => 5, :timeout => 3) { #redis logic }
```

Answer (score 1):

Internally ConnectionPool::Wrapper creates a normal ConnectionPool object, and uses method_missing to automatically checkout/checkin from that pool whenever any method is called on the wrapper.

This use of method_missing includes calls to `inspect`, or `class`, or any number of methods which are normally used to try to look at the object or figure out its type.

```rb
require 'connection_pool'

class MyClass
  def foo
    'bar'
  end
end

obj = MyClass.new
obj.respond_to?(:foo) # true
obj.respond_to?(:with) # false  

wrapper = ConnectionPool::Wrapper.new { MyClass.new }
wrapper.respond_to?(:foo) # true
wrapper.respond_to?(:with) # also true! 'with' is a method on ConnectionPool::Wrapper
```

You do have an instance of ConnectionPool::Wrapper, it just is a bit hard to tell.